# Wrong landscape window size in AVD with skin (Nexus 7)

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

In portrait mode it works perfectly but in landscape I have wrong screen size. 
How can I resize it?

[image]

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to fit window size to borders of the device.